# boot strap hidden panel visible for a sec on page load

Tags: javascript, html, .net, bootstrap-4

we recently moved to bootstrap and ran into this issue. I have a error message label set to show only when there are errors but on page load it shows for a sec when it is supposed to hide.

```
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

var error = $("#MainContent_lblError").text();
        if (error != '') {
            $("#pnlError").show()
        }
        else { $("#pnlError").collapse('hide') };
    });
```

Comment: SO hide it by default with CSS.....

Comment: Since you are hiding the element with javascript code, it does not run until the whole page is loaded. Add the class="hidden" to the element tag by default, then your javascript function will show or hide the element without it showing up on page load.

Comment: When i add class="hidden" to the element tag it is not showing even when it  should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what fixed my issue

```
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  var error = $("#MainContent_lblError").text();
        if (error != '') {
            $("#pnlError").removeClass("hidden").addClass("alert alert-
danger")
        }
        else { $("#pnlError").removeClass("alert alert-
danger").addClass("hidden") };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file add a style

```
#pnlError {

    display:none;

}
```